# comparing a list within linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following query:

```
var zoneIds = filter.Zones.Select(s => s.ZoneId);

var playerQuery = this._cmsDbContext.PlayersLoader.Query(user.ClientId);

var sortedLocationIds = playerQuery
  .Where(w => zoneIds.Contains(w.ZoneId))
  .GroupBy(g => g.LocationId)
  .Select(s => s.Key);
```

The problem I'm having is as following: If the list with zoneIds contains more then 1 `zoneId`, i only want to return the locations which has all of the zoneid's in the list. As of now i return every location that I find any hit on within the zoneId list.

So if `zoneIds` contains lets say `zoneId = 1` and `zoneId = 5`, i only want the locations which has players with `zoneId` *1* and *5*. Now i get every location that has either zone *1* or *5*.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

*edit,

here are the classes im working with:

```
public class Location : IEntityBase
    {
        public Location()
        {
            Players = new List<Player>();
            Filters = new List<Filter>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }

        public int? ProfileId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProfileId")]
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

        public int StoreNumber { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LocationName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Homepage { get; set; }

        public int LocationActive { get; set; }

        public int? ClusterId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClusterId")]
        public virtual Cluster Cluster { get; set; }

        public int? RegionId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Filter> Filters { get; set; }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }

     public class Player : IEntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }

        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

        public int ProfileId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProfileId")]
        public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }

        public int ZoneId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ZoneId")]
        public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }

        public int NrOfScreens { get; set; }

        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public int PlayerActive { get; set; }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastContactDate { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 3)]
        public int ComputerStatus { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 3)]
        public int ScreenStatus { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 3)]
        public int ExtStatus { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastServiceDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant entity classes with the relevant properties?

Comment: How do we get all zones of a player? Your example only displays a single property `ZoneId`.

Comment: one player only has one zone, a location has multiple players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `!zoneIds.Except(locationGroupZoneIDs).Any`:

```
var sortedLocationIds = playerQuery
    .GroupBy(w => w.LocationId)
    .Where(g => !zoneIds.Except(g.Select(w => w.ZoneId)).Any())
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Another approach, probably more readable but a little bit less efficient:

```
var sortedLocationIds = playerQuery
    .GroupBy(w => w.LocationId)
    .Where(g => zoneIds.All(id => g.Select(w => w.ZoneId).Contains(id)))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: I liked the first approach much better. Thank you very much Tim, It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

```
var zoneIds = filter.Zones.Select(s => s.ZoneId);

var playerQuery = this._cmsDbContext.PlayersLoader.Query(user.ClientId);

var sortedLocationIds = playerQuery
    .SelectMany(w => w.Players.Where(p=>p.ZoneId == w.ZoneId))
    .Select(s=>s.LocationId)
    .Distinct();
```